# JS function should affect all divs with same class

Tags: javascript, html

My function only works with the first element.

**What do I have to change so that all elements with the class .folder are affected by the function `update`.**

```
<div class="folder"></div>
<div class="folder"></div>
<div class="folder"></div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName('colorOut');

      for(var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
        radioButtons[i].addEventListener('change', update, false);
      }

     function update() {
        var paragraph = document.querySelector('.folder');
        paragraph.className = 'folder';
        for(var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
          if (radioButtons[i].checked) {
            paragraph.classList.add(radioButtons[i].value);
          }
        }
      }

      update();
});
</script>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector` selects first element. `document.querySelectorAll` will select all the elements and returns a NodeList.

Comment: @ManojKumar Not an array - a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), there's a difference.

Comment: @Oka Thanks. Just rectified.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
document.getElementsByName
```

that's the wrong syntax, you need:

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```